# .openshift/action_hooks/post_start_php not executed if hot_deploy is set. Why?

Tags: drupal, openshift, marker

I use the `hot_deploy` marker, but I found that .openshift/action_hooks/post_start_php will not be executed.

Why? How do I make it be executed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because when you add hot_deploy you tell the server to no longer stop or start on build and deploy. You could move the script to a post_build and that will still execute.